# Fix pylance import error by shifting working directory one level up to cover the imported code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have this structure for my project:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── config
│   ├── database
│   ├── logging.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── routers
│   ├── services
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── utils
│   └── worker
├── k6.js
├── poetry.lock
├── prestart.sh
├── pyproject.toml
├── pytest.ini
└── run.py
```

Inside app, I have this `worker` folder that I also open as a kind of separate project.

```
├── __init__.py
├── database
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── conn.py
├── engine
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core
│   ├── data
│   ├── main.py
│   └── utils
├── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── run.sh
```

The issue that I have when I open `worker` project which uses code from upper directory, pylance gives me an error of an import that could not be resolved. However, this code runs fine and perfect.

[image]

I created `.vscode/settings.json` for the worker project and add these options:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["../../app"],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["../../app"]
```

But I am still getting these errors! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

These paths fixed my issue:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/../.."],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/../.."]
```